# How to print using Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am having a *pdf*, now how can I print the **PDF** file from my app??

Is there any *PrintManagerTask* or something similar to that??

Comment: Do you want cloud printing or remote printing? Be specific in question.

Comment: No i just want remote printing(wireless)

Comment: You can try with [Google cloud print API](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/).